# iphone app with role based login?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, role-based

Can iPhone apps have role based login?

In my application I have to display the content according to the role of the user (employee, visitor). Till now I havent seen any app with role based login for iphone.
Can I develop role based login? is there any restriction from apple side for these kind of logins to approve the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your app has a login, you are supposed to give Apple a login/password to test the app.  If they notice that there are multiple roles, I would assume that Apple would want to be able to test each role.

Comment: Providing login credentials according to the role are not a problem i can provide them. One thing which I wanted to know is role based login is possible or not in iphone? whether apple will approve it not?

Comment: You are limited to what you are capable of programming, as always.  Many apps have logins and have been approved by Apple.  There is no restriction on role based logins.